# How to use Bootstrap side navbar and routing in angular 5?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular5, navbar

I am new to **angular 5** but i knew **angular-JS 1.x**..

I have navbar designed in bootstrap which is work well with **angular-js 1.x** . 
I decided to move on to **angular 5** but i don't know how to convert since each module are called as component in angular. is there a way to implement bootstrap/material Navbar in **angular 5**?

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started: I would place the navbar in a separate component. Then place that component in the top of (for instance) the app.component.html and use routing to navigate through the router outlet:

```html
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The html for the navbar would be the navbar as you now it. Use Angular routing as described in the Angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: will try and let you know.. thanks for your help @Stefan